# Symfony 2.2 always sendme to login page after login

Tags: php, session, symfony, authentication

I havea a simple login system on Symfony 2.2.1 the problem is when to go secured area yes show the the login form and input user and pass but always go send me to `/login` page, sometimes send me to `/`. looking in the log i get the following

```
[2013-04-22 20:25:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] request.INFO: Matched route "login_check" (parameters: "_route": "login_check") [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.nombre AS nombre2, t0.contrasena AS contrasena3, t0.salt AS salt4 FROM usuario t0 WHERE t0.nombre = ? LIMIT 1 ["rkmax"] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.nombre AS nombre2 FROM rol t0 INNER JOIN usuario_rol ON t0.id = usuario_rol.rol_id WHERE usuario_rol.usuario_id = ? [8] []
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] security.INFO: User "" has been authenticated successfully [] []
...
[2013-04-22 20:25:02] security.WARNING: Username "" could not be found. [] []
```

as you can see the the user is empty when is write in the SecurityContext but i dont know the reason.

### Classes and settings

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('MySecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

two entities `Usuario` (User) and `Rol` (Role) both implements interfaces for speak with the symfony security

```
class Rol implements RoleInterface

//Repository/Usuario
class Usuario extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($login)
    {
        $usuario = $this->findOneBy(array('nombre' => $login));

        if (!$usuario) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                sprintf("El usuario '%s' no existe o el nombre esta mal escrito", $login)
            );
        }

        return $usuario;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $usuario)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($usuario);
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Iscltda\SecurityBundle\Entity\Usuario';
    }
}

class Usuario implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contrasena", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $contrasena;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Rol", inversedBy="usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="usuario_rol",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rol_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $rol;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rol = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getNombre();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set contrasena
     *
     * @param string $contrasena
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setContrasena($contrasena)
    {
        $this->contrasena = $contrasena;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contrasena
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContrasena()
    {
        return $this->contrasena;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Add rol
     *
     * @param \Iscltda\SecurityBundle\Entity\Rol $rol
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function addRol(\Iscltda\SecurityBundle\Entity\Rol $rol)
    {
        $this->rol[] = $rol;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove rol
     *
     * @param \Iscltda\SecurityBundle\Entity\Rol $rol
     */
    public function removeRol(\Iscltda\SecurityBundle\Entity\Rol $rol)
    {
        $this->rol->removeElement($rol);
    }

    /**
     * Get rol
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRol()
    {
        return $this->rol;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->rol->toArray();
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->getContrasena();
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        $this->getNombre();
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Serializes the content of the current User object
     * @return string
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return \serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->nombre,
            $this->salt,
            $this->contrasena
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Unserializes the given string in the current User object
     * @param serialized
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->nombre,
            $this->salt,
            $this->contrasena
        ) = \unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

the `routing.yml` settings

```
login:
    pattern: /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: MySecurityBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern: /admin/login_check

logout:
    pattern: /admin/logout
```

this are my `security.yml` settings

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyVendor\MySecurityBundle\Entity\Usuario:
            algorithm: sha256
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity: { class: MyVendor\MySecurityBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: nombre }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            provider: user_db
            security: true
            pattern:    ^/admin
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

### update

i found the problem is I return nothing in the method `getUsername` i change to

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->getNombre();
}
```

but still remains send me to the login page

### update 2

i found the last problem in the UserProvider class the method `refreshUser` was wrong i've changed to

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $usuario)
{
    return $this->loadUserByUsername($usuario->getUsername());
}
```

with this works propertly